# Unique identifiers in dynamic form (ng-repeat)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form with input texts that are looped in a ng-repeat.

For every input field there is a switch with which the user sets "Use default value" to YES/NO.

Every row of input fields are basically two fields, with one hidden one at a time, whether you want to show the default value (switch: YES, input text = disabled) or set a custom value (switch: NO)

I need each element to have a unique identifier to be able to save it on submit, for example **id="title_{{spec.id}}".

The switches work so that the **switch-variable** is used to create 2way binding, but it is the value of the checkbox within the Switch-DIV that will be saved to the database.

What I think I need to do is apply the **spec.id** value to the **switch-variable="useDefaultValue_{{spec.id}}"** and set the same value to the **ng-show="useDefaultValue_{{spec.id}}"** and **ng-hide**, but I don't know how to.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row form-group" ng-repeat="spec in specsList">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
            <label for="specification_">{{spec.title}} <span ng-show="spec.unit.length">({{spec.unit}})</span></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title_{{spec.id}}" id="title_{{spec.id}}" placeholder="Not visible" ng-model="spec.value" ng-hide="useDefaultValue">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="spec.defaultValue" ng-show="useDefaultValue" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
            <label for="useDefaultValue_">Use default value</label> - {{spec.useDefaultValue}}<br />
            <div class="switch" init-switch switch-variable="useDefaultValue">
                <input type="checkbox" id="useDefaultValue_{{spec.id}}" name="useDefaultValue_{{spec.id}}" ng-model="spec.useDefaultValue">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your checkbox is backed by the row-dependent spec.defaultValue, you can come up with a simpler solution and don't need the switch. Just reference `spec.useDefaultValue` instead of your current `useDefaultValue` to directly access it.

```
<div class="row form-group" ng-repeat="spec in specsList">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
            <label for="specification_">{{spec.title}} <span ng-show="spec.unit.length">({{spec.unit}})</span></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title_{{spec.id}}" id="title_{{spec.id}}" placeholder="Not visible" ng-model="spec.value" ng-hide="spec.useDefaultValue">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title_{{spec.id}}" id="title_{{spec.id}}" ng-model="spec.defaultValue" ng-show="spec.useDefaultValue" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
            <label for="useDefaultValue_">Use default value</label> - {{spec.useDefaultValue}}<br />
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="spec.useDefaultValue">
        </div>
    </div>
```

As an aside, I would also use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` and `ng-hide` to lighten the page and make the transitions smoother.

**EDIT** Submit function :

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    angular.forEach(specsList, function(spec, index) {
        if (spec.useDefaultValue) {
            $scope.user[spec.title] = spec.defaultValue;
        }
        else {
            $scope.user[spec.title] = spec.value;
        }
    });
    User.save(user).$promise.then(function(persisted) {
        // do some post-save cleanup
    });
};
```

Of course, this is assuming you save spec values on the user. They could be stored somewhere else.

Comment: Not sure that I am following here, but I need to use the switch, because the selection of "Use default value" = YES/NO is a setting that the user changes and then saves to the database. The switch works so that the **switch-variable** is used to create 2way binding. I also assume that each element needs to be named using the spec.id as a unique identifier so it is possible on submit to save the information correctly. I have changed the checkbox to **ng-checked="spec.useDefaultValue"**. Maybe that is more correct.

Comment: Actually, no, you are using ng-checked wrong; it is intended to create "slave" checkboxes because the basic checked value is not saved by the browser. See angular doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked ; also, you don't need the switch because of the two-way binding on spec.useDefaultValue : when the user is about to save, just iterate over specList, and you can associate spec.useDefaultValue with spec.id without having to use the switch.

Comment: Thanks for the info about ng-checked. Seems like I am not able to explain what I am trying to achieve. The switch is needed because I want it there, it is part of the editing process made by the user. If the user sets the switch "Use default value" to YES they are not able to edit a custom value, and for that row the switch value TRUE will be saved to the DB. If they select NO they will be able to set a custom value in the **input text="title_{{spec-id}}"**. So each checkbox (within the switch-DIV) needs a unique ID to know which row it belongs to.

Comment: I realized that I named both input text fields to **title_{{spec.id}}** which of course is wrong. Only the one where the user sets the custom value needs an ID since it is the only one that will be saved if the switch is set to NO.

Comment: The confusion may have to do with how you perform your save. I was assuming that there is a submit button somewhere, that calls a function. If this is not the case, could you explain what the switch does exactly (is it a directive you implemented ? If so, could we see the code ? unless I am mistaken, this is not standard angular) and how you save your data ? I will edit my answer to show what I think the submit could look like.